# Push StandardValueSet for ContractStatus into a Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx

I simply want this to be pushed into a new scratch org

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>In Approval Process</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>In Approval Process</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Activated</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Activated</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Draft</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Draft</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Sent</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Sent</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Received</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Received</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Final</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Final</label>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>
```

Executing `sfdx force:source:push -u my-SCRATCH` gives me this

> src/main/default/standardValueSets/ContractStatus.standardValueSet-meta.xml
>   Field: null is not a picklist (19:20)

At these point I deleted `Sent`, `Received` and `Final` statuses from the xml file, pushed and it worked. Good. Then, I created these statuses in a scratch org manually:
[image]

`sfdx force:source:status`

[image]

After that I pulled these changes with `sfdx force:source:pull`

[image]

When I created a fresh new Scratch org, I again got the initial error

> Field: null is not a picklist

This is awkward, sad, confusing... How can I push `ContractStatus.standardValueSet-meta.xml` into a scratch org?

My guess is that it must be something connected to `Status Category`. Each picklist item is associated with it, but there is no relevant property that describes it in metadata schema [StandardValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customvalue.htm#standardvalue).

I am using this `sfdx-project.json`:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "src", "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "47.0"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT 12/2021]: Looks like the issue is fixed. I was able to retrieve and then deploy ContractStatus StandardValueSet. `groupingString` is now part of the metadata file.

[ORIGINAL ANSWER]:
Unfortunately this is currently a bug in the Metadata API.

We've been talking about it for a while, and I currently have a Case open for it.
Please add your voice to the discussion on the Trailblazer Community on [this thread](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003NmQ4c), the more people asking for it, the more likely they fix it.

Create another case may help too.

[EDIT]: A Known Issue has been created for this, have a look [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YnUtQAK)